# PHP how to autoinclude?

Tags: php

I have a following project structure:

```
\
|- FolderA
|  |- FolderB
|  |  |- index.php
|  |- index.php
|- index.php
|- config.php
```

I want my config.php to be loaded automatically (without 'include' directive inside index.php) whenever I access:

```
http:://MySiteName/index.php
http:://MySiteName/FolderA/index.php
http:://MySiteName/FolderA/FolderB/index.php
```

Or any other php file in my project.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: As I know there is no way to do this

Comment: @Gazler - I don't think that's realistically possible, unless he writes such autoload code in each `index.php`, which kind of defeats the purpose of not using `include`.

Comment: @Lu4 - I don't usually question the OP's purpose, but this time it's quite strange. See my answer below...

Comment: Please rephrase "I don't usually question the OP's purpose, but this time it's quite strange"

Comment: As in, why do you want to do this? People usually rely on the main index file and deny direct access to others ones.

Comment: I was using code igniter for some time, and it had nice feature that allowed to autoload the required libraries, but now when I'm using raw php it seems rather strange to include everything. By the way there are some constants defined in config.php, which are used during include like "include APPPATH . 'index.php';" It is impossible to use those constants until the config.php is included..

Comment: How can I rely on the main index file?

Comment: Ok, my answer is complete and tested, please give it a look.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting all the `auto_prepend_file` answers, at least leave a comment as to why

Comment: Crazy idea, but being offensive to people who are trying to help you isn't generally a great long-term approach.

Comment: I don't want to be offensive, really I'm not, but what if somebody is offensive to you?

Comment: @Lu4 You can flag offensive posts for moderation

Answer (score 4):

The only way to make this works is to use the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) php.ini directive:

```
auto_prepend_file = /path/to/config.php
```

Or in a *.htaccess*:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file config.php
```

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can think about (other than `auto_prepend_file` which may land you in some trouble), is to use an `.htaccess` file to actually load into a specific boot file which loads the actual file.
Example follows:

```
\
|- FolderA
|  |- index.php
|- index.php
|- config.php
|- boot.php
|- .htaccess
```

Contents of `boot.php`:

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');
    $real_file = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    include_once($real_file);
?>
```

Contents of `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ boot.php [NC]
</IfModule>
```

So, basically, we're telling it that all requests ending with `index.php` should be sent to `boot.php`.
This `boot.php` simply loads your config, and then loads the original `index.php` file, whatever subfolder it is in. The rewrite rule was tweaked over `index.php` files only, so that images (and other files) work correctly. If you have other files, like `index2.php`, just modify the htaccess regex accordingly.

Comment: what troubles might auto_prepend_file cause?

Comment: The host server might not allow you to set it, it can be disabled from htaccess, ini etc... Oh, and to future devs, it might not be that obvious.

Comment: That's going to fall over pretty badly if `mod_rewrite` is not available.

Comment: It's *always* available :). Cheap hosts are starting to allow it as well. Setting INI settings _always_ failed on such cheap/shared hosts. By the way, if the INI setting failed, how would it fall any more gracefully?

Comment: Oooo. This is beautiful. +1 (Came here from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969388/php-how-to-autoinclude-with-cgi-fastcgi))

Answer (score 1):

If you're running an Apache web server, place the following in the `.htaccess` file in your root web directory:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/absolute/location/of/config.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can dynamically alter your PHP configuration (via `.htaccess` or local `php.ini`) to limit changes to your application, you could try using the [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.

Comment: what if I'm using namespaces, prepending not namespaced php code probably will cause error?

Comment: @Lu4 I'm not sure what you mean. Any non-namespaced code is placed into the [global namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

Comment: If you are using namespaces you can't have code outside namespace, if the config file (which has no namespace) will be prepended to index.php file then index.php (which has namespace) will have mixture of both non-namespaced and namespaced code which might cause error...

Comment: @Lu4 Any file included using `auto_prepend_file` is merged in the same manner as `require` (you would know this if you read the manual page). It's not magically prepended to the actual script

Comment: Thank you for your answer Phil Brown, it was really helpful. I'm considering to use your solution. But it would be nice if you would have been more indulgent to people you are communicating with. I take your "you would know this if you read the manual page" as an offense...

Comment: @Lu4 Had you read the manual page that both myself and @netcoder linked to? You can take that statement how ever you want but it is just that, a statement, a fact.